# Node.js app example using dependency injection

Tags: angularjs, node.js, dependency-injection

I really like how dependency injection is done in angular, so I would like to use similar pattern in node. There are a lot of modules which tends to be DI containers and it's not easy to choose.

Are there any real-world examples of using DI in node? How to structure the application in that case?

Comment: DI is just a pattern of providing dependencies to constructors, which has the added benefit of making the object easy to test (because you have explicated each dependency.) So, passing in all dependencies to module.export = function someConstructor(...) instead of using require('someService') within the constructor is a way to achieve that. This isn't exactly like using DI in Angular, but it might give you the benefits of DI that you're looking for without a larger framework.

Comment: Just an hint better than nothing :) https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/39598/node-modules-di-return-a-object

Answer (score 3):

I had a really sexy answer on mocking for tests, then I re-read your question and ... ugh.

The whole `exports`/`require` mechanism provides dependency injection, and you can mock out - or swap out - any module that you need to by simply changing the `require('module')` to point to the new one.

You can even wrap any alternative, API-compatible library sets that you might want to switch out.  For example, if you were approaching a nervous breakdown while deciding to move from [underscore](https://www.npmjs.com/package/underscore) to [lodash](https://www.npmjs.com/package/underscore), you could just create a module called 'underdash.js' with this:

```
if (process.env.COLD_SWEATS || process.env.SHAKING || process.env.PALPITATIONS) {
    module.exports = exports = require('underscore');
} else {
    module.exports = exports = require('lodash');
}
```

And then when you need it, just `require('./underdash')` and now you don't have to care about which downspacesque library you're actually using and can change it at the flip of a switch - *SO LONG AS THE APIs ARE THE SAME, otherwise you're gonna have a bad time*.

Answer (score 0):

I developed and have been using [systemic](https://www.npmjs.com/package/systemic) in production for a year. It's a re-write of a [electrician](https://www.npmjs.com/package/electrician), developed for [TES](https://www.tes.com) (heavy node.js users). Both are less magical than angular's DI mechanism. You might also like [diogenes](https://www.npmjs.com/package/diogenes).

There's an example systemic application [here](https://github.com/guidesmiths/svc-example).

Answer (score 0):

You can use [injecute](https://www.npmjs.com/package/injecute) for this purposes.

Example below relevant to typescript but you can just omit the types and use with plain javascript.

```js
import { default as Express, Handler } from 'express';
import { ArgumentsKey, Func, DependenciesTypes, DIContainer, IDIContainer } from 'injecute';

// helper that helps to pull services from container
export const useContainerServices =
  <S extends Record<ArgumentsKey, any>>(container: IDIContainer<S>) =>
    <
      Keys extends readonly (keyof S)[],
      RequiredServices extends DependenciesTypes<S, Keys>,
      H extends Func<RequiredServices, Handler>
    >(
      servicesNames: [...Keys],
      handlerCreator: H
    ): Handler => {
      return container.injecute<() => Handler, any, any>(handlerCreator, servicesNames);
    };

// business stuff service
class MyBusinessService {
  constructor(private readonly logger: any) {}

  doBusinessStuff(parameter: string) {
    this.logger.log(parameter);
    return Number(parameter);
  }
}

// root app container
const c = new DIContainer()
  .addInstance("logger", console)
  .addSingleton("businessService", MyBusinessService, ['logger']);

// handler creator bounded to your app container
const useServices = useContainerServices(c);

const app = Express();

// use handler on route
app.use('/api/business/stuff/:id', useServices(
  ["businessService"],
  (service) => (req, res, next) => {
    res.json(service.doBusinessStuff(req.params.id));
  }
));

app.listen(3000)
c.get('logger').log('Listening at port 3000')
```